# Cooldown for commands using Node/TMI.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I'm currently using TMI.js which is a Node package for building a bot in Twitch. However I could really use a cooldown system ~ where once you do one command
    !test This is a test command.
You need to wait 10 seconds for it to trigger again, if you try to use it within those 10 seconds I want nothing to happen.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the server running the whole time or is this test command starting a new process?

Answer (score 1):

Write a cooldown wrapper function:

```
// thisArg - context in which to call the function; 'this' in the function's body
// fn - function to execute on a cooldown
// timeout - number of milliseconds to wait before allowing fn to be called again
var cooldown = function (thisArg, fn, timeout) {
    var onCooldown = false;

    // return a function that can be called the same way as the wrapped function
    return function (/* args */) {

        // only call the original function if it is not on cooldown
        if (!onCooldown) {

            // not on cooldown, so call the function with the correct context
            // and the arguments with which this wrapper was called
            fn.apply(thisArg, arguments);

            // set the cooldown flag so subsequent calls will not execute the function
            onCooldown = true;

            // wait <timeout> milliseconds before allowing the function to be called again
            setTimeout(function () {
                onCooldown = false;
            }, timeout);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var cooldownLog = cooldown(console, console.log, 5000);

cooldownLog('hello')   // => 'hello'
cooldownLog('hello')   // nothing happens
cooldownLog('hello')   // nothing happens

// > 5000ms later
cooldownLog('hello')   // => 'hello'
cooldownLog('hello')   // nothing happens
```

Comment: Okay Matt, that work. But the syntax for sending a message to chat is `if(message === "Test") {  client.say("Channel I want to send message", "This is a test command");`  } and when I tried `client.say("My channel", cooldownLog("Test command"));`  I got TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined. How would I make thios work?

Comment: In my example, I wrapped the `console.log` function in a cooldown and called it `consoleLog`. You'll want to wrap `client.say`. Perhaps `var clientSay = cooldown(client, client.say, 10000)`, and then you can call it the same way: `clientSay('My channel', 'Test command')`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide more information about what is happening at each step.

Comment: Note that wrapping `client.say` in that way will not set the cooldown on a per-response basis; it will only allow `client.say` to be called once every `timeout` milliseconds, regardless of the channel or message. You would have to create a cooldown for each response if you desire it to be per-response. e.g.`var msg1Cooldown = cooldown(client, client.say, 10000); msg2Cooldown = cooldown(client, client.say, 10000);`

Answer (score 1):

By using `setTimeout({function}, x)` you can have a function run after x milliseconds.

So we can have a boolean called `active`. Which is set to `True`, 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds) after the command has been run once.

If the user tries using our command whilst `active == False` then we can tell the viewer that the command is still on a timeout

```js
var active = true;

// Whenever someone uses the command the below code is an example
client.on("message", (channel, userstate, message, self) => {
    if (message[0] == "!" && !(self)) {
        message = message.replace("!", "");
        switch (message) {
            case "test":
                if (active) {
                    // Do command stuff

                    active = false;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        active = true;
                    }, 10000);
                } else {
                    // Do stuff if the command is in cooldown
                }
                break
        }
    }
})
```